# Using different hadoop-mapreduce-client-core.jar to run hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, jar, java-opts

I'm working on a hadoop cluster with CDH4.2.0 installed and ran into [this](https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/DISTRO-461) error. It's been fixed in later versions of hadoop but I don't have access to update the cluster. Is there a way to tell hadoop to use this jar when running my job through the command line arguments like

```
hadoop jar MyJob.jar -D hadoop.mapreduce.client=hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.0.0-cdh4.2.0.jar
```

where the new mapreduce-client-core.jar file is the patched jar from the ticket. Or must hadoop be completely recompiled with this new jar? I'm new to hadoop so I don't know all the command line options that are possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how that would work as when you're executing the `hadoop` command you're actually executing code in the client jar.

Can you not use MR1? The issue says this issue only occurs when you're using MR2, so unless you really need Yarn you're probably better using the MR1 library to run your map/reduce.

Comment: This might sound silly but how do you run a MR1 job? Is that hadoop-0.20?

Comment: Use the package: org.apache.hadoop / hadoop-client / 2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.2.0. Basically change the version from "2.0.0" to "2.0.0-mr1"